# FFMPEG make thumbnail and add watermark one command

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I need a onc ffmpeg command to first make thumbnail and after this add watermark to video output.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
"[1]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5,scale=iw*30/100:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w-5):y=(main_h-overlay_h-5)/(main_h-overlay_h-5),drawtext=fontfile=myfont.ttf: \ text='mysite.com': fontcolor=white@0.5: fontsize=18: x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10" -codec:a copy -movflags +faststart OUTPUT.jpg OUTPUT.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[1]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5,scale=iw*30/100:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w-5):y=(main_h-overlay_h-5)/(main_h-overlay_h-5),drawtext=:text='mysite.com': fontcolor=white@0.5: fontsize=18: x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10,split=2[vid][img]" -map "[vid]" -map 0:a? -codec:a copy -movflags +faststart OUTPUT.mp4 -map "[img]" -frames:v 1 OUTPUT.jpg
```

You did not provide any errors so I assumed the following problems:

- Need `-frames:v 1` for jpg output to avoid error  `Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'OUTPUT.jpg'. Use '-frames:v 1' for a single image, or '-update' option, or use a pattern such as %03d within the filename.`
- Use filter output labels (`[vid][img]` in the example) and refer to them with [`-map`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) so both outputs use the result from filters.
- A filter output can only be consumed once, so use the [split](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split) filter to make two copies.